# In the US, are Inquisitorial trials always mandatory in possess of certain inquisitorial evidences?

Tags: united-states

If, for example, an investigation finds out that a CCTV recorded a suspect committing murder, is it still mandatory for them to have the right of a trial or it can be skipped and they can be immediately imprisoned?

Comment: FYI. CCTV is rare in the USA and tends to be in private hands only- very rarely is there government sanctioned surveillance without a warrant. This falls under "unreasonable search and seizure" which is also prohibited by the Constitution.

Comment: @AffableGeek - wonder if there's a major legal difference between CCTV and mobile device media (e.g. Boston bombers). I'm guessing evidentiary chain of custody may come into play for the latter.

Comment: @DVK That sounds like the beginnings of a good question: What is the admissibility of privately held surveillance footage (e.g. the Lord & Taylors in the Boston bombings) in a federal trial?  Hint, Hint, hint...

Comment: @AffableGeek - Where's Legal.SE when you need it? :(   Seems offtopic here.

Comment: @AffableGeek I have CCTV security in my house I have 3 other neighbors that also do as well as some friends in other cities.  For about 300 you can get a decent setup... its more common than you realize

Comment: @Chad  Did you not see that I was differentiating between private and public video?  I specifically said its often in private hands which is a whole different kettle of fish!

Comment: @AffableGeek - I can provide my CC video to the police though  and they do not need a warrant.  They only need a warrant if I refuse to give it to them consent to search it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trials aren't necessarily mandatory if the accused opts out, but it is a right citizens have. We have the 6th Amendment that addresses this:

> In all criminal prosecutions, the accused shall enjoy the right to a speedy and public trial...

More information at Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10362/discussion-between-ben-collins-and-chad)

Answer (score 4):

The [other answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/1885/4666) may be a bit misleading, depending on how one reads the question.  Before being imprisoned as a **punishment**, there must be a trial.  However, suspects may be detained by police for a reasonable period of time (e.g. forty-eight hours).  And a prosecutor may, during that time, go before a judge and charge the suspect.  The judge may then either release the suspect (possibly on payment of bail) or remand the suspect to jail.

With greater evidence of guilt, it is easier to remand a suspect to jail without bail.  You will sometimes hear a sentence as including *time served*.  That's the time spent in jail prior to sentencing, during and prior to the trial.

Note that the purpose of confinement in this situation is to prevent suspects from harming themselves or others or to prevent flight.  As such, defendants (or their attorneys) will often argue that they are not such a danger and not a flight risk.

It is possible for a suspect to be detained and confined without trial.  But they then have the right to a speedy trial.  They also might under some circumstances (e.g. if it were shown that the CCTV footage was faked) have the right to release because the evidence was in their favor.

Trial can't be skipped, but people who are obvious dangers to society can be imprisoned prior to trial.

Comment: Valid answer, though we should point out there is a difference between "prison" and "jail'. You can't (typically) go to *prison* without a trial (unless you opt out of it). You may wait in *jail* pending said trial. So, technically, you can't be *imprisoned* pre-trial, but you can be *jailed*.

Comment: Also a fairly obvious problem: it is not possible to positively identify a person from CCTV footage, or even from a decent photograph.  There have been a number of cases where people have been charged, and sometimes even convicted, by such evidence despite proof that they were elsewhere when the footage was taken.